# How to get the "label" of "Allowed Values" for a text list programmatically?

Tags: 8, entities

I created a text list field on the user entity.  I entered the following for **Allowed values list:**

```
apple|A delicious apple
pear|A very delicious pear
orange|A not so delicious orange
```

I can access the key for the field like this:

```
$current_user->get('field_list_fruits')->value,
```

which returns `apple`.  But how do I get the text `A delicious apple` programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the field config and look for the key/value pair from the allowed value list?

Much easier though is using the field formatter for this field type [OptionsDefaultFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21options%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21OptionsDefaultFormatter.php/class/OptionsDefaultFormatter/9.1.x):

```
$build = $user->field_foo->view(['type' => 'list_default']);
```

What you do with $build depends on the use case. Put it in a render array to be rendered later or

```
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

if you need it now and can't wait until the page is rendered, for example if you want to send an email.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I'm using a custom JSONAPI endpoint to return just the rendered value, so I used `$build[0]['#markup']`.

Comment: or render only one field item `$user->field_foo->get(0)->view(['type' => 'list_default']);`